# Sails model validation only when updating and not while creating

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

While using sails validation I need some fields only to get validated while updating and not during creation. The scenario is that when the user is getting creating the i am just taking username and password and later I ask for all the remaining data for the user and I need to apply some validation rules only during updation and not creation.

I know I can do some manual validation using lifecycle callback beforeUpdate but then I wont be using sails validation which I think is not the proper way.

How can tell the model that these rules need to be applied only during updation?

Answer (score 1):

what rules specifically? One thing you can do is give the rules a true/false check to see if the record has as an Id. If it does, then its an update, if it does not, then its a create.

```
favorite_color : {
    required : function(){
       return 'id' in this // ID should be your primary key field. 
    }
}
```

I will say it would be nice if you could specify when validations occur, but currently you can not.

Comment: Thanks Meeker! This can be one work around but what I am doing right now is using the beforeUpdate callback for this purpose and using the validator.js directly which sails is also using for validation purpose !

Answer (score 0):

You may split DB entity into two separate entities and use two models. First model will require username and password and second model will require other fields.